# Where did the expression "to up the ante" come from?

Tags: etymology, idioms

I know what it means, but I cannot understand where it could have come from.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Upping the ante](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/up+the+ante) comes from betting games.  The ante is the amount that all players must commit to the "pot" *before* the game begins.  (The pot is what is won in the game, and will be the total of the ante plus all bets during the game.) Because a player must at minimum "ante up," or pay the ante, in order to be allowed to play the game, upping the ante can quickly demonstrate how serious, committed, and solvent a player is.

The significance of "upping the ante" is that it increases the overall cost of the game, hence the idiomatic meaning of "increasing the cost or risk of something."

Comment: ante - apparently from L. *ante* "before"

Answer (score 5):

In poker, an ante is a forced bet that all players must risk. Upping the ante simply means to raise stakes. The risk is bigger, but so is the reward.

Answer (score 0):

Ante means “before” in Latin. That’s where the Spanish “antes” comes from and it’s the real origin of the English expression.

Comment: How does this explain the meaning of "to up the ante", specifically?

Answer (score -1):

Ante means *before* in Spanish, so it comes from there, before the game (of poker or whatever) starts.

Comment: It is cognate in Spanish, but that's not its origin.